# Column invalid or group by in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project in which I have to display the products and quantities.

This is my query:

```
select DATEDIFF(month,T3.startdate,T3.enddate) warranty_duration, 
T2.ItemCode,T2.Quantity,T2.SerialNum,T4.ItemName,T2.SerialNum as 
InternalSN,T3.ContractID,T3.issend,
T3.StartDate,T3.EndDate,T3.Remarks1 from ORDR T1
inner join RDR1 T2 on T1.DocEntry=T2.DocEntry 
inner join OCTR T3 on T1.CardCode=T3.CstmrCode
inner JOIN OITM T4 ON T2.ItemCode=T4.ItemCode
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),T3.enddate)<=7 and 
DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),T3.enddate)>=0)
and T3.isSend=0
and T4.SWW in ('PSG','IPG-H','ESSN-N','ESSN-ISS','ESSN-HPN','ESSN-
BCS','EABMS')
and t3.contractID = 23890
```

My Query shows result like this:

[image]

---

I want to show like this:

[image]

Comment: You have 11 columns in your query and 3 in your expected results. Do you want 3 columns or 11?

Comment: i want 11 column , this is just an example what i want my result to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DATEDIFF(month,T3.startdate,T3.enddate) warranty_duration, 
T2.ItemCode,T2.Quantity,T2.SerialNum,T4.ItemName,T2.SerialNum as 
InternalSN,T3.ContractID,T3.issend,
T3.StartDate,T3.EndDate,T3.Remarks1 from ORDR T1
inner join RDR1 T2 on T1.DocEntry=T2.DocEntry 
inner join OCTR T3 on T1.CardCode=T3.CstmrCode
inner JOIN OITM T4 ON T2.ItemCode=T4.ItemCode
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),T3.enddate)<=7 and 
DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),T3.enddate)>=0)
and T3.isSend=0
and T4.SWW in ('PSG','IPG-H','ESSN-N','ESSN-ISS','ESSN-HPN','ESSN-
BCS','EABMS')
and t3.contractID = 23890 
GROUPBY T2.ItemCode
```

Comment: Or whatever column you want to group your results by

Answer (score 0):

> GROUP BY **productName**

(change bolded value to your own in DB) should do the trick.